# How to show another Widget after signal from existing window app? (both guis converted from ui using pyuic5)

Tags: python, class, widget, pyqt5

**How to show/load another Widget after button click in existing Window?**.

Having converted two GUIs from QtDesigner into python code, I have trouble starting the second widget from inside the first widget "loop". How can I start another object (class) inside another class/loop?
Programme is lagging, a new window pops up white and only for a second, everything crashes, no error given, exit code: 255.
My efforts so far are below (see comment in start function):

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):

    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        ...

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        ...

    def start(self): # this gets activated by a button

        # here I try to invoke another window app (class) unsuccessfully
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
        Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        ui = Ui_Form()
        ui.setupUi(Form)
        Form.show()

class Ui_Form(Ui_MainWindow):

    def setupUi(self, Form):
       ...
    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
       ...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For starters, you already have a `QApplication` instance running at the point where you create the form so you should skip the line `app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)` in `Ui_MainWindow.start`.

To get to the issue of the window only appearing for a split second: when you create your widget in `Ui_MainWindow.start`, you create it as a local variable `Form`. This means that when `Ui_MainWindow.start` exits, `Form` is destroyed together with all the other local variables. To get your widget to exist outside `Ui_MainWindow.start` you could make it an instance variable of you `Ui_MainWindow` object, i.e.

```
def start(self): 
    self.Form = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    ui = Ui_Form()
    ui.setupUi(self.Form)
    self.Form.show()
```

I don't know if this will solve the crashing issue, but it should at least make your widget appear for more than a second.

Comment: Thank you very very much! It finally works! Sorry for such probably infantile question, but object oriented programming etc. is pretty new to me, I have to dive deeper into it. Thank you once again!

Comment: Unfortunately, sth new came up. I am wondering whether deleting the app line made it impossible for my second_Ui to be fully responsive. I mean: although there are buttons in Ui_Form connected to its (Ui_Form's) methods / functions, when I click on them, nothing happens, even print doesn't work.